# why 'false' is not printed?

Tags: jquery, coffeescript, jsfiddle

I am following the example from coffeescript [cookbook](http://coffeescriptcookbook.com/chapters/syntax/comparing_ranges)

and I am playing a bit with this example:
http://jsfiddle.net/andilab/N8DP3/2/

```
normal_false = 1<2<2 #false -> is NOT printed

normal_true  = 1<2<3 #true -> is printed
```

wondering why `false` is not printed until used with JSON.stringify, is it matter of coffescript or JSFiddle or jQuery?

Comment: Some languages will print boolean `false` as empty, I suppose JavaScript is one of them.

Comment: Also just appending another string to it seems to force it to become a full string eg `out.append '|'+normal_false+'|'`. It may be that append has some kind of overload type thing that will do something special if it is passed a boolean that causes the true and false to go down different lines. For what its worth a standard `out.append false` does exactly the same so you can simplify away the range comparison stuff.

Comment: After further playing this is in fact related to jquery's append function and not even coffeescript...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is caused by the use of jQuery's `append` function.

Append calls various things and at some point calls `buildFragment` to turn the argument provided into an HTML fragment to add.

In this function is the following:

```
if ( elem || elem === 0 ) {
    ... //Most of the code that generates stuff
}
```

elem in this case will be `false` and so it skips over it.

I assumed this line is defined to catch "undefined" things being passed in and just happens to catch false too. Further than this I can't say why the code is like this but its that line of code that does it.

Reference: http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.0.js

Comment: I updated the fiddle to demnostrate that this is `fault` of jquery append method.